# Find the domain of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{6x^2+3x+3/4}+x}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My attempt:
Let's assume that $\sqrt{6x^2+3x+\frac{3}{4}}+x$  $>$ 0$$
 \rightarrow\sqrt{6x^2+3x+\frac{3}{4}}  > -x
 \rightarrow {6x^2+3x+\frac{3}{4}}  > x^2\\
  \rightarrow {5x^2+3x+\frac{3}{4}}  > 0\\$$
  If x $<$ 0 then $x^2$ $>$ 0, and ${5x^2+3x+\frac{3}{4}}  > 0$ 
 the domain is $(-\infty,+\infty)\\$
 But, I'm not totally convinced. Any help is appreciated.
 Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We have two cases to check.

First,  $$6x^2 + 3x + \frac{3}{4} \ge 0$$

It is $\ge 0$ for all $x$.

Next, $$6x^2 + 3x + \frac{3}{4} - x\ne 0$$

$$6x^2 + 2x + \frac{3}{4} \ne 0$$

Solving we get complex values for $x$. Therefore, no real values exist for $x$.

Thus, you are correct. The domain is: $(-\infty, \infty)$

Answer (score 2):

All we need is $\sqrt{6x^2+3x+\dfrac34}+x\ne0$ and of course  $6x^2+3x+\dfrac34\ge0$

$6x^2+3x+\dfrac34=6\left(x+\dfrac14\right)^2+\dfrac34-\dfrac6{16}>0$  for all real $x$

Now $\sqrt{6x^2+3x+\dfrac34}+x=0\iff x=-\sqrt{6x^2+3x+\dfrac34}\le0$

$\sqrt{6x^2+3x+\dfrac34}=-x$

Squaring we get $5x^2+3x+\dfrac34=0$ but $5x^2+3x+\dfrac34=5\left(x+\dfrac3{10}\right)^2+\dfrac34-5\cdot\dfrac9{100}>0$  for all real $x$

So, the denominator is non-zero real for all real $x$